# What happened to my comments?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-comments

The question is [Database - No output from the fields of db table [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71042085).

I closed this question yesterday as a dupe of [mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter / Call to a member function bind_param() errors. How to get the actual mysql error and fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22662488)

OP seems very upset at this so I've tried to walk them through the process of

1. Editing their question to provide clarity, and
2. Possibly getting their question re-opened if the current duplicate *really* doesn't help.

I had a comment like this (from memory because it's been deleted)

> You said you're getting the "Nope" message which means `mysqli_query()` failed. This doesn't happen without errors, you just need to configure your code to see them. The duplicate shows you how to do this. Once you have the error message, it's usually simple to find the fix. If that still doesn't help however, please edit your question to add info and request to have it reopened.

I had a few other comments asking for clarity (one with multiple upvotes) which I would have manually deleted once OP updated their question. I try to be as good as possible in comment clean-up once they become irrelevant.

Right now, all but my last comment has been deleted but all of OP's comments remain.

What's happening here? Did I do something wrong?

---

#### Update

All the comments have been removed now which at least seems cleaner. I won't add any more but I'd still like to know why only mine were initially removed.

Comment: Obligatory "comments aren't permanent, use answers instead", but also obligatory "if you're commenting, then why did you close the question and/or did the dupe satisfy the OP's question"?

Comment: "but all of OP's comments remain." - no they don't. A number of their comments have been deleted as well

Comment: @Makoto I'm responding to OP's comments

Comment: @Zoe I saw you deleted the last insulting one (thanks) but I'm referring to the ones I responded to and OP's replies to those. The comment thread is incomprehensible right now because OP's comments are still there

Comment: Classic situation of using a dupe to point to a common but ambiguous failure to debug connection issues. New user is upset, because they just want you to fix their problem, not give them more work. Sorry Phil, that's the way it goes sometimes. As for the comments themselves, there seems to be a quite large amount of excessive comment deletion lately. It would be nice to see a moderator explain themselves here, especially since during election they always claim they will in circumstance like this. So let's see it.

Comment: @TravisJ I do sometimes feel a pang using that dupe target given its _"teach a person to fish"_ philosophy but I also have no problem reopening a question once it's been shown that the dupe doesn't help

Comment: @Phil - It isn't easy when only half of the picture is given and you are asked to complete the rest. Nothing wrong with using the dupe target like that, heck look at the Null Pointer post.

Comment: I can't see the comments, but from what you describe they weren't needed. Probably someone flagged them and they got removed. Good riddance. The question will be gone soon too so I don't see an issue

Comment: All the information the user needs is in the duplicate so it's not like by deleting comments we have left them without solution.

Comment: The comments on that question were deleted by multiple moderators, including myself (I deleted the one which was remaining when I viewed the question several minutes ago). I've pinged the moderator who deleted the comments I *think* you're asking about. The short answer is that all deleted comments were either deleted automatically (the auto "Does this answer your question?" comment), flagged, or were the ones you were complaining about being confusing by remaining.

Comment: @Makyen I can only assume the poster flagged my comments (like the example above) but I'd really like to know what was wrong with it in order to actually be removed. And why didn't the same moderator (at the time) delete OP's comments too? Seems very odd to delete only one half of a conversation thread and I don't find anything insulting, conversational or irrelevant in what I wrote given what I was responding too

Comment: You must have been doing something very right for the past 12 years if you have to only now be taken aback by comments disappearing into the night :) But still at some point you realised that this is a heavily curated site, right? So it should not come as TOO much of a surprise that these things happen. Stick around on meta for a while, you'll see several questions about it in a single week at this point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry about leaving a mess behind. A bunch of the comments were flagged and I didn't double check to see if there were any more that would require action as a result.

Of the ones I deleted, some of them were flagged as being "unfriendly or unkind" and others as being "no longer needed". Sometimes it can be difficult to decide whether the former flag is deserved or just someone feeling aggrieved about something, so occasionally things get deleted that shouldn't have done or left when they should have been deleted.

Unfortunately due to timezones I wasn't able to see this until now. Had I seen it earlier I might have been able to clean things up better.